# Data Structure for Multilevel Key

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the best data-structure for efficient level search, when the key is function of multiple values.
Say my Key is `[Row Key] [Column Name] [ TimeStamp ]`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a multi-dimensional index or aggregate index?

Aggregate indexes combine several keys (timestamp, row key, ...) into a single key which is then stored in a normal search index (Hashmap, B-tree or similar). Aggregation can be done by concatenating the keys or interleaving their bits.

Multidimensional indexes allow indexing and searching for several attributes at the same time. For example if you have `[ID] [attr1] [attr2] [timestamp]` then you could use a 4-dimensional index. You would have to turn all values into integers or floats (for Strings you could use turn the first few characters into an integer). For look-up, you can simply those dimension empty where you don't know the value.
Multi-dimensional indexes are for example R*-Tree, X-tree, PH-Tree. There are also the kd-tree and quadtrees, they are quite simple to implement but not really that good for large datasets or many dimensions.